# meta_query to check all custom fields

Tags: custom-field, meta-query, term-meta

I have to use the `meta_query` argument so that it checks for a keyword in all available custom field values (in array format) saved for the object. The meta keys are different for every object, therefor I can't use any static key.

This is something I want to achieve.

```
'meta_query' => array(
    'relation' => 'OR',
    array(
        'key' => 'state', // This is where I am lost
        'value' => 'mykeyword', //Keyword to look for
        'compare' => 'EXISTS' //If keword exists in value (array)
    ),
),
```

Can this be done using `meta_query` or do I need to use custom database query?
Thanks

Comment: I’m afraid that the only solution is to use custom SQL with LIKE using posts_where and posts_join filters

Answer (score 0):

Short of coming up with a MySQL query yourself, you could get a list of distinct `meta_key`s and build your query array based on the results.

On another note, I think you may have misunderstood the meaning of `EXISTS`. It doesn't denote finding the `value` parameter passed within the value of the given meta. I think you *actually* mean `LIKE`, but please correct me if I'm wrong.

```
$query_arg = array(
    ...
);

global $wpdb;

$meta_keys = $wpdb->get_col("SELECT DISTINCT `meta_key` FROM {$wpdb->postmeta}");

foreach($meta_keys as $meta_key){
    $query_arg['meta_query'][] = array(
        'key' => $meta_key,
        'value' => 'mykeyword',
        'compare' => 'LIKE'
    );
}

$query_arg['relation'] = 'OR';
```

Although this is likely not the most optimised way of doing things, from a MySQL standpoint.